# List all known NumPy arrays currently in Python interpreter

Tags: python, numpy, garbage-collection

I want a collection of all numpy arrays currently managed by my Python interpreter.  Previous answers suggest that `gc.get_objects()` should do this for me.  However I don't get expected results:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import gc

In [3]: x = np.ones(5)

In [4]: any(item is x for item in gc.get_objects())
Out[4]: False
```

Is there a way to get all of the known NumPy arrays (or objects of any type really) currently instantiated?

Comment: For reference, from Jim Crist internal communication at Continuum Analytics: This explains why gc.get_objects doesn't work: https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2014-September/071186.html Numpy contains a tool for tracking allocations as a context manager. This plus a `WeakSet` could possibly help solve your problem. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/tools/allocation_tracking

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a perfect answer, but according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430811/enumerate-or-list-all-variables-in-a-program-of-your-favorite-language-here) you can use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) to get a dictionary of all of the locally declared variables.

You can then get all of the known NumPy arrays using simple dict comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
np_arrays = {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if isinstance(v, np.ndarray)}
```

You can then iterate over the dictionary however you like after that.

Comment: I believe that locals only provides local scope, not variables allocated elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed, this would not reveal items allocated to class members of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this addresses the exact problem you're trying to solve, but what about using `locals()`?  That gets you started on at least getting what vars are being kept track of by the interpreter of your current interactive session?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
filter(lambda x : isinstance(x, np.ndarray), locals().values())
```

Comment: I believe that locals only provides local scope, not variables allocated elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can find numpy arrays with `gc.get_objects()` if you expand the objects recursively, as explained [here](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/GetAllObjects)

```
# code from https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/GetAllObjects
import gc
# Recursively expand slist's objects
# into olist, using seen to track
# already processed objects.
def _getr(slist, olist, seen):
  for e in slist:
    if id(e) in seen:
      continue
    seen[id(e)] = None
    olist.append(e)
    tl = gc.get_referents(e)
    if tl:
      _getr(tl, olist, seen)

# The public function.
def get_all_objects():
  """Return a list of all live Python
  objects, not including the list itself."""
  gcl = gc.get_objects()
  olist = []
  seen = {}
  # Just in case:
  seen[id(gcl)] = None
  seen[id(olist)] = None
  seen[id(seen)] = None
  # _getr does the real work.
  _getr(gcl, olist, seen)
  return olist
```

Now we should be able to find [most](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/GetAllObjects) objects

```
import numpy as np
import gc

x = np.ones(5)
objects = get_all_objects()
print(any([obj is x for obj in objects]))
# will return True, the np.ndarray is found!
```